# How to bypass the character while import in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I am trying to import the documents in MongoDB using Mongoimport as:

```
mongoimport -d database -c collect --file abc.json
```

The file is extremely large, i.e. 200 GB.
I am getting the following error:

```
2017-03-24T15:07:52.275+0530    Failed: error processing document #848744: inval
id character '\x00' in string literal
2017-03-24T15:07:52.276+0530    imported 848743 documents
```

This is because of the `UTF-8` Character, I suppose.
I want to know how I can bypass this? I would like to know without BSON conversion or using MongoDump, how I can use Mongoimport for the import functionality?
Kindly, help me.

Comment: BSON can only be encoded in UTF-8. Why don't you encode your "abc.json" file in UTF-8? (can be done very easily with software like [iconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) on unix os

Comment: @felix I would love to. But file is 200+ GB and I do not want BSON. I would like to have json only. This is the only thing I can import as for BSN I need to do a lot of changes to my program which I want to avoid at this moment.

Comment: BSON is just the storing format inside mongodb, so no need to convert your json to BSON, but just change the encoding of your json file to UTF-8 before running mongoimport

Comment: Is it possible to do it while importing itself... I mean you can imagine 200 GB + 200 GB = 400 Gb of data where do I go?

Answer (score 2):

you can convert your json to UT-8 in the same time

assuming your running this on a unix system :

```
iconv abc.json -f ASCII -t UTF-8 | mongoimport -d database -c collect
```

change `ASCII` by your current file encoding

you can get it with this command:

```
file -i abc.json
```

Comment: oops I forgot to mention I am using windows 8.1